# Databricks Access local notebook

Tags: databricks

I have created some notebook on Databricks and I wanted to access them. One notebook has the local path

```
/Users/test@gmx.de/sel2
```

If I now try to access the directory via

```
%fs /Users/test@gmx.de
```

I am getting an error message saying that the local directory is not found.

What do I make wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Notebooks, to my knowledge can't be accessed through `%fs`, when you try something with `%fs <dir>`, it means you have some data or resource mounted at  `<dir>` location which is different from workspace where you keep your notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebooks aren't a real objects located on the file system.  Notebook is in-memory representation and are stored in the database in Databricks-managed control plane.  Here is the architecture diagram from [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/getting-started/overview.html):

[image]

If you want to export notebook to local file system you can do it via [databricks cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html) or via UI.  Or you can include it into another notebook via `%run`, or execute it from another notebook with [notebook workflow](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html) (`dbutils.notebook.run`).  And you can run tests inside it with some tools like Nutter.